# Fetch data from DB on every pageload

Tags: django

I basically need to make a DB query on every view within an app, in order to pass some data to my templates. Since views are not classes, but simple functions, I can't have a construct, where I can do the query.

So, structurally speaking, what is the best practice on where to put this kind of logic? I probably could just create a template tag and do the queries there, but it seems like not very well organized to me.

Comment: What do you mean by you don't have a construct where to do a query?

Comment: `views.py` consists of functions, so naturally there is no class, so that I can do application logic inside that class' constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, views certainly can be classes: Django has offered [class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/class-based-views/) since version 1.3.

However, the best way to pass data to every template is to use a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext).